# Why $\mathcal{M}^p([0,T],R^d)$ is a Banach Space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, banach-spaces, stochastic-calculus

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0},P)$. Let $1\leq p < \infty, $ a process $x(t)$ $\in \mathcal{L}^p([0,T],R^d)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\{ x(t), t \in [0,T]\}$ is $\mathcal{B}([0,T])\times\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(R^d)$ measurable, $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted, $R^d$-valued processe such that:

$$\int_{0}^{T} |x(t)|^p dt < \infty, a.s.$$

Let $x(t) \in \mathcal{M}^p([0,T],R^d)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x(t) \in \mathcal{L}^p([0,T],R^d)$ and satisfies:
$$E\int_{0}^{T} |x(t)|^p dt < \infty.$$

It is easy to check that $\mathcal{M}^p([0,T],R^d)$ is a normed vector space with the norm:
$$||x||_p = \left(E\int_{0}^{T}|x(t)|^p dt \right)^{1/p} < \infty.$$
Here is the question:

Why $\mathcal{M}^p([0,T],R^d)$ is a Banach space?

My idea:

Let $\{x_n(t)\}_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathcal{M}^p([0,T],R^d)$ a Cauchy sequence, then we know that there exists an element $x(t)$ in $L^p([0,T]\times \Omega, \mathcal{B}([0,T])\times\Omega, dt\times dP)$(normal  product measure space) such that:
$$E\int_{0}^{T}|x_n(t) - x(t)|^p dt \rightarrow 0,\ \ \ \ (n \rightarrow \infty).$$

We want to show $\mathcal{M}^p([0,T],R^d)$ is a Banach space, then we need to prove that $x(t)$ must be in $\mathcal{M}^p([0,T],R^d)$. How do we know $x(t)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process from the condition $E\int_{0}^{T}|x_n(t) - x(t)|^p dt \rightarrow 0,(n \rightarrow \infty)$.

Comment: Is $\mathcal F_t$ complete?

Comment: yes, $\mathcal{F}_t$ is an increasing sub $\sigma$ algebra of $\mathcal{F}$ satisfying usual conditions( right continuous and complete)

Comment: Maybe BDG inequalities and u.c.p topology might be of help as the space of semimartingale is complete under the associated norm (https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/u-c-p-convergence/) theorem 2